# somar posições de um array

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho uma serie de `array` dentro de um `array` e gostaria de fazer a soma apenas da primeira posição de cada `array` (no caso somar todos os numeros'2') e me retornar o valor ('no caso daria 6'). Obrigado

```
var dados =[
    [ '2', '1404' ],
    [ '2', '1406' ],
    [ '2', '9000' ],
]
```

Comment: Apenas por curiosidade, esse [código](https://ideone.com/kvcVKD) soluciona o problema de maneira eficiente apenas no Navegador Safari pois este já conta com [Optimização Tail Call](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=146477) em [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). Nos outros navegadores não deve ser utilizado pois o código apresentará baixa performance com arrays grades gerará o erro `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Quem se interessar pelo assunto [Proposta ECMA TCO](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-tail-position-calls)

Answer (score 3):

Você tem inúmeras maneiras de fazer isso.

Podendo ser um laço com `for` tradicional:

```js
const dados = [ [ '2', '1404' ], [ '2', '1406' ], [ '2', '9000' ] ];

let soma = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
  soma += parseInt(dados[i][0]);
}

console.log("Total:", soma);
```

Pode usar o método `reduce`:

```js
const dados = [ [ '2', '1404' ], [ '2', '1406' ], [ '2', '9000' ] ];

const soma = dados.reduce( (acumulador, valorAtual) => {
  return acumulador + parseInt(valorAtual[0]);
}, 0);

console.log("Total:", soma);
```

Pode também utilizar um `for of`:

```js
const dados = [ [ '2', '1404' ], [ '2', '1406' ], [ '2', '9000' ] ];

let soma = 0;

for (const dado of dados) {
  soma += parseInt(dado[0]);
}

console.log("Total:", soma);
```

> Documentações:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score -2):

Pode ser feito usando o [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const dados = [ [ '2', '1404' ], [ '2', '1406' ], [ '2', '9000' ] ];


// Uma linha de código
console.log(dados.reduce((acc, cur)=> acc + parseInt(cur[0]),0));
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda irei aplicar aqui

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado!